# Adding PDFBox to my filepath so I can use it in Java (IDE is Dr. Java)

Tags: java, filepath, pdfbox, drjava

I've just recently downloaded PDFBox for use in Java (IDE is Dr. Java). It is currently located in my Downloads folder, so I'm assuming I have to specify a filepath so Java can access it. How do I set a filepath in Java so that it knows where to locate PDFBox? (or, if this assumption is incorrect, how do I get Java to recognize and utilize PDFBox?)

Also, I assume I'm going to have to use an IMPORT statement before my main class declaration and was wondering what statement should I use for PDFBox? (i.e. for Scanner, using import java.util.Scanner)

Thanks!

Comment: Import is needed yes, I would look into Classpath, and understand how you link stuff in, You should be using an IDE, Idea, Eclipse or even Netbeans.

Comment: Are you just starting to learn programming? The best is to use an IDE (netbeans, eclipse, intellij). If you have one, edit your question to include its name. Your question is probably a duplicate... read on 1) java command line option "-cp", and 2) the concept of "classpath". I recommend Netbeans, as it is great for beginners.

Comment: Yeah I'd say I'm anywhere from novice to intermediate. I've been coding for a while but am mostly self-taught after taking an Intro to Java course a couple years ago.

Comment: Re PDFBox imports, the best is to download the source code, there are many complete examples, and they'll have the imports you need, and you'll learn from there.